# How to change behavior of QValidator for lineEdit:

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have set up a QRegExpValidator for my lineEdit to accept numbers in format 111.111 or 111,111 or 111.

When user enters '111,' - validator's state is Intermediate. But when user presses enter or lineEdit looses focus (imagine user made a type error) - text inside lineEdit 'freezes'. I wish '111,' would change to acceptable value in this situation, for example to '111'.

How can I do that? I guess it is something about QValidator.fixup() function or subclassing the whole QValidator.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore,  QtGui


class Mainwindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("window")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.layout =  QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        regexp = QtCore.QRegExp("^\\d+[\.,]\\d+$|^\\d+$") #accepts numbers in format 111.111 or 111,111 or 111
        validator = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(regexp)

        self.lineEdit.setValidator(validator)
        

        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(lambda: print(self.lineEdit.text()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = Mainwindow()
    application.show()


    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "freezes"?

Comment: @musicamante I mean the Intermediate state doesn't change and a value, which is invalid in fact, remains in lineEdit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to override the `fixup()` method.

Note that in C++ the `input` argument is modifiable, that's why according to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#fixup) it seems it returns nothing ("`void`").
In PyQt this is not possible, because strings are immutable types, so the return signature is different than it's C++ counterpart (see [release notes about QValidator](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/python_v3.html#qvalidator)) so that it can actually return a string.

```
class Validator(QtGui.QRegExpValidator):
    def fixup(self, input):
        while input.endswith(('.', ',')):
            input = input.rstrip(',')
            input = input.rstrip('.')
        return input


class Mainwindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        validator = Validator(regexp)
        # ...
```